# CSS or jQuery solution to select "last in hierarchy" elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a bunch of nested HTML elements, like

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div>A</div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div><span>B</span></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to only select the innermost divs, those that do not contain any other divs? Notice that div B does have descendants, but no other divs.

**Clarification** i mean to select all those divs that do not contain another div, but maybe some other tags.

Comment: While this is a valid question, it would probably be "better" just to find a way to give these elements a `class` and just style them that way. Whatever is outputting this HTML certainly has more control than CSS or JS, and giving these elements a class when you output them will avoid a potentially hacky CSS/JS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to only select the innermost divs, those that do not contain any other divs?

You could combine the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)/[`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors in order to select the innermost `div` elements that don't contain other `div` elements:

```
$('div:not(:has(div))');
```

Given the HTML you provided, if you don't want the `div` with the "A" text node to be selected, you could only select elements that contain other elements, in this case a `span`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zx9breag/)

```
$('div:not(:has(div)):has(*)');
```

Answer (score 3):

Can do something like:

```
$('div').not(':has(div)').css('color','red')
```

explanation is ambiguous though so not 100% clear that this is expected result

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8t9Ljsp/)**</kbd>